# Redshift - SQL script to extract value from a key value pair

Tags: json, regex, amazon-redshift

I have a columns containing JSON data as below. I am trying to extract values corresponding to each key pair in the column. Could anyone advice how could I do using SQL

```
 [{"id": 101, "id1": {"key": "SaleId", "type": "identifier", "regex": null}, "id2": {"key": Name, "type": "identifier", "regex": null}, "id3": {"key": null, "type": "identifier", "regex": null}}]
```

Key values are id1, id2, id3

Expected output:

```
id1 : SaleId
id2 : Name
id3 : null
```

I am using Redshift. Thanks

Comment: Is that example data correct? Because it's not valid JSON: Name should be in double quotes e.g. "Name" for this to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Redshift, so this might not Work.
It Works in JavaScript:

```
/"(id\d)":\s\{"key": "?(\w+)"?/g
```

You will then have to extract `Group 1`, containing the `id` and `Group 2`, containing the `key`.

The regex starts by matching a double quote, then creating a Group with the Word 'id' followed by a digit, a colon, a Space, a left curly brace, a double quote, the Word 'key', a colon, a Space, an optional double quote. Finally it creates a Group with one or more Word characters, followed by an optional double quote.

As I said, I don't know Redshift, for instance, you might have to escape double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need like this

```
with t as
    (
    select '[{"id": 101, ' ||
           '"id1": {"key": "SaleId", "type": "identifier", "regex": "null"}, ' ||
           '"id2": {"key": "Name", "type": "identifier", "regex": "null"}, ' ||
           '"id3": {"key": "null", "type": "identifier", "regex": "null"}}]' as str
    )
select 'id1:' || json_extract_path_text(substring(str,2,length(str)-2),'id1','key'),
       'id2:' || json_extract_path_text(substring(str,2,length(str)-2),'id2','key'),
       'id3:' || json_extract_path_text(substring(str,2,length(str)-2),'id3','key')
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string in your example is invalid because `Name` is not in double quotes.

Assuming this is a typo and this is meant to be a valid JSON string, then you can use [JSON functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html) to extract the values you need from the column.

Example (I have added quotes around "Name"):

```
create temp table jsontest (myjsonstring varchar(1000))
;
insert into jsontest(myjsonstring) 
    values ('[{"id": 101, "id1": {"key": "SaleId", "type": "identifier", "regex": null}, "id2": {"key": "Name", "type": "identifier", "regex": null}, "id3": {"key": null, "type": "identifier", "regex": null}}]')
;
select 'id1', json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(myjsonstring, 0) , 'id1', 'key') from jsontest
union all
select 'id2', json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(myjsonstring, 0) , 'id2', 'key') from jsontest
union all
select 'id3', json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(myjsonstring, 0) , 'id3', 'key') from jsontest
;
```